# My plot from matplotlib is working too slow, is there are way for more efficiency?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

When I open the plot or want to zoom it all is working very slow. Can you say, maybe I can something change there are for more efficiency (productivity)?
Data is about ~1600 numbers.
My numbers just in typical list format, like [1,2,3], I don't use pandas and getting that data from csv file (see picture 2, please).

[Picture 1 - The plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QES7V.jpg)

[Picture 2 - CSV file of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOIK5.jpg)

```
    with open(r"C:\Users\Idensas\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\f.csv",'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in f.readlines():
        y.append(i[0:8])
        x.append(float(i[9:15]))
```

Comment: I am sorry, sure, I will do it now.

Comment: Well, you should also convert the time stamps from string to something like a datetime object, or just numbers like hh + mm / 60 + ss / 3600. Pandas would make things easier.

Comment: Thank you, going to learn more about it, have a good day ^^